# Capture input in the child process after spawn in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn, google-home

I'm working on a small cli tool that can automatically deploy Google Home actions based on the projects that are setup in a directory.

Basically my script checks the directories and then asks which project to deploy. The actual command that should run is coming from Google's cli [gactions](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)

To run it with arguments I setup a spawned process in my node-script:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const child = spawn('./gactions', [
    'update',
    '--action-package',
    '<PATH-TO-PACKAGE>',
    '--project',
    '<PROJECT-NAME>'
])

child.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data)
}
```

However, the first time a project is deployed, the gactions cli will prompt for an authorization code. Running the code above, I can actually see the prompt, but the script won't proceed when actually entering that code.

I guess there must be some way in the child process to capture that input? Or isn't this possible at all?

Comment: The child process's `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are streams, so you can manipulate them as you like. The node documentation gives you a very simple [example](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio) as a starting point.

Comment: Ok. But how do I capture that input when prompted for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply pipe all standard input from the parent process to the child and all output from the child to the parent.

The code below is a full wrapper around any shell command, with input/output/error redirection:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
var child = spawn(command, args);

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);

child.on('exit', () => process.exit())
```

Note that if you pipe `stdout` you don't need handle the `data` event anymore.

Comment: That worked. I probably need to read-up some more about piping data in node. Any recommendations by any chance for good documentation on this subject?

Comment: you should read about working with streams, that's the wider topic. The official node docs about [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) is a good starting point, but you can always google for more

Comment: Cool. Thanks mihai!

Comment: Spawn has third argument - `options`. Pass `stdio` and then configure stdin, stdout, stderr pipes i.e.
`spawn(command, args, { stdio: ["inherit", "inherit", "inherit"] })`

More on stdio: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

Answer (score 4):

```
require( "child_process" ).spawnSync( "sh", [ "-c", "npm adduser" ], { stdio: "inherit", stdin: "inherit" } );
```

this will execute the command given as we normally do in terminal.

Comment: good suggestion but the first answer worked liked charm for me. thanks